# Server Agent not saving Excel file

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am unable to save an Excel workbook using the code below on a server with a scheduled agent but it works on when I run it locally.

Error I get is:

> **Agent Manager: Agent message: INITIALIZE:   - Error #213 - Microsoft Excel: SaveAs method of Workbook class failed @ line #37**

We have Excel 2016 installed on Windows Server 2012. Domino Server version is 8.5.3 FP6

Code using:

```
Declarations
Dim xlApp As Variant, xlsheet As Variant, rows As Integer, cols As Integer, xlWorkBk As Variant
Dim SheetRows() As Integer  'the bound for sheetRows is the same as the sheetNukmber
Sub Initialize
        On Error GoTo ErrorTrap
        Dim st As String, aname As String, sname As String

        st = CStr(GetThreadInfo(1)) + ":  "
        Dim sess As New NotesSession ,db As NotesDatabase
        Dim agent As NotesAgent
        Dim v As NotesView, vString As String, strMsg As String
        Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
        Dim doc As NotesDocument, maxcols As Integer
        Dim a As Integer, range As String 
        Dim mgrList() As String, mgrTotal() As Currency
        Dim  x As Integer, mgrPcntg() As Double'GET SERVER NAME (COMMON)

        Set db = sess.CurrentDatabase   'link to current database
        If InStr(db.server,"/") Then
            sName = Left(db.Server,InStr(db.server,"/")-1)
        Else
            sName = db.server
        End If
        'GET AGENT NAME (COMMON)
        Set agent = sess.currentAgent
        If InStr(agent.name,"|") Then
            aName = Left(agent.name,InStr(agent.name,"|")-1)
        Else
            aName = agent.Name
        End If

        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  'start Excel with OLE Automation
        xlApp.Visible = False
        xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    '- - - - - - Adding data from Notes here - - - - -
    '- - - - - - formatting worksheet - - - - - -

    '- - - - - - I Get Error 213 at Next Line - - - - - -
    'INITIALIZE:   - Error #213 - Microsoft Excel: SaveAs method of Workbook Class failed @ Line #37
        Call xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\Temp\MikesTest.xlsx", 51) ',51)
        xlApp.Quit
        GoTo EndOfCode
ERRORTRAP:
        strMsg =  st +  " - Error #" & Err & " - " & Error$ & " @ line #" & Erl
        MsgBox strMsg
        xlApp.quit
        Exit Sub
ENDOFCODE:

End Sub
```

Checked permissions of agent signer and it is allowed. Checked file folder restrictions and there is none. Searched Internet for hours with no success in finding solution.
Tried `xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\Temp\MikesTest.xlsx")` and same issue.

Comment: You said there are no folder restrictions on c:\temp, does that mean anyone (including the service account Domino is using) can save there?  Can you create a text file in that folder?

Comment: Is the same Windows user name used for accessing the folder on the server as is the user name/workstation used when running on local?  Make sure the security permissions on the Windows folder itself allows for the server user to modify files within.

Comment: Security in the Folder Properties for C:\Temp says SYSTEM has full control.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have had to run the server as an application rather than a service so that the user name running the Domino server was in the Active Directory.  Only then would the agent work in the background.  If you do come up with a way for SYSTEM to have application access to the Domino server, let me know.  Cheers.

Comment: Got it to work by making a few changes to our server.  Starting with Windows 2008, Microsoft changed security model.  IBM was extremely helpful although this is not their problem.  This is what we did.  For the IBM Domino Service, changed the properties under the Log On tab to use an account to log on.  Stopped and restarted the Domino service.  Next we added the following directory "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop".  It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by making a few changes to our server. 
Starting with Windows 2008, Microsoft changed security model. IBM was extremely helpful although this is not their problem. This is what we did. 
1. For the IBM Domino Service, changed the properties under the Log On tab to use an account to log on. 
2.Stopped and restarted the Domino service. 
3.We added the following directory "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop".
4. Saved the file to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is, but it could be the `activeWorkbook` attribute of the `xlApp` object that might not make sense in the remote context you are working in on your server. Instead when you open the new workbook, assign it to a variable, and then use that workbook object variable directly to save it:

```
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  'start Excel with OLE Automation
    xlApp.Visible = False

    Dim xlWB As Object
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

    xlWB.SaveAs("C:\Temp\MikesTest.xlsx", 51) ',51)

    Set xlWB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
```